# Reachability: empty flags when calling TryGetFlags twice

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator, reachability

I have this code to test network connection:

```cs
        if (remoteHostReachability == null) {
            remoteHostReachability = new NetworkReachability (HostName);

            // Need to probe before we queue, or we wont get any meaningful values
            // this only happens when you create NetworkReachability from a hostname
            reachable = remoteHostReachability.TryGetFlags (out flags);

            //remoteHostReachability.SetCallback (OnChange);
            remoteHostReachability.SetNotification (OnChange);
            remoteHostReachability.Schedule (CFRunLoop.Current, CFRunLoop.ModeDefault);
        } else {
            reachable = remoteHostReachability.TryGetFlags (out flags);
        }
```

When calling it first time, flags are ok. But, when calling it second time, flags are always equals to **zero**. Tested on iOS Simulator 5.0.

What's the problem? In both [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Classes_Reachability_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Classes_Reachability_m-DontLinkElementID_6)'s and [Xamarin](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/master/ReachabilitySample/reachability.cs)'s examples NetworkReachability created once.

Comment: Please note that first time `TryGetFlags` is calling from background thread (`InvokeInBackground`).

Answer (score 0):

I've found when using Reachability, rather than testing the remote status, I just ensure the host is reachable.

```
Reachability.HostName = "www.google.com";
var reachable = (Reachability.InternetConnectionStatus() != NetworkStatus.NotReachable) && Reachability.IsHostReachable("www.google.com");
```

Comment: I want to get status change event too, rather then checking it periodically.